# Visual Studio Code projectName

Tags: java, json, debugging, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code for Java debugging, there must be `projectName`defined in the **launch.json** file for using the watch-window while debugging.

How to determine and/or define the name of the Java project?

I always get the error message:

> Failed to resolve classpath: The project '??' is not a valid java
>   project.

Here my launch.json extract:

```
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch)-Application<foo>",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "mainClass": "FooClass",
        "args": "",
        "projectName": "??",
        "windows": {
            "classPaths": [
                "%CLASSPATH%","C:\\JUnit\\junit-4.12.jar", "C:\\JUnit\\hamcrest-junit-2.0.0.0.jar", "."
            ]
         }
```

Comment: There might be a bug with [Java Test Runner](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/34). Solution: create a Java project with Eclipse and open it with VS Code. Important are the .project and .classpath files. (or use templates and work with copies of them)

Comment: Try to remove "projectName". Just "mainClass" should work.

Answer (score 11):

For Maven projects(at least) you can find the project names at the bottom of the vscode sidebar under MAVEN PROJECTS.

[image]

You can also look for .project files inside your projects.
The projectName is there in the name attribute.

[image]

*I'm not expert on this at all, but I was struggling with this too, so I hope it can help someone else!

Comment: What to do if I have multiple web projects in the workspace? Should I put in entry project only?

Answer (score 10):

i was going crazy trying to figure out why the update i made to .project and pom.xml didn't change the project name in vs code...

1. edit projectDescription / name in .project
2. edit artifactId in pom.xml
3. here's what i did to get it to reload and show the updated project name:

[image: update project name]

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#failed-to-resolve-classpath

Answer (score 6):

The VSCode contains JAVA PROJECTS on the sidebar.
I am using SSH plugin to connect to a machine where the project actually resides (VS Code runs locally) so the name of the java project is my name and some hash to it

[image: VSCodeSideBar]

Recent version (2023 - click to enlarge)
[image: ProjectIdentifierUpdated]

After adding the hash "_c4503cca" to the projectName in launch.json, the watches in debug mode work fine.

Comment: now it works with codebling answer on github
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/843#issuecomment-1066236388

Right-click on a Java file (one without a main() function) and choose "Run Java" and you'll get a prompt with a few options. This prompt will show the project name.

Comment: Yet another approach
Explorer-> Java Projects-> Click Debug on the project itself and the dialog appears
(updated the answer with the screenshot)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the extension Debugger for Java (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug), then the `projectName` is the name of the directory that your project is in.

For instance, if your project looks like the following.

```
my-project/
  src/
    main/
      java/
        myproject/
          Application.java
  .project
  pom.xml
```

Then `projectName = "my-project"`

Answer (score 1):

setting `projectName: ""` works

otherwise, go to the Java Projects -> right click on project -> Reveal in Explorer and it shows the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this thread while searching for "Failed to resolve classpath: The project '??' is not a valid java project.". In my case the culprit was rather silly. I have multiple projects within one parent folder and one common `build.gradle` in the root folder. E.g.:

```
parent/
├── abc/
├── def/
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

The "??" in my case was referring to one of the projects, be it `abc`. After modifying `settings.gradle` in root folder to contain the following line problem seems to be gone.

```
rootProject.name = 'gat'
```