# In `launch.json`, what should `projectName` be when attaching to remote java application?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When debugging Java in VSCode, if I reach a breakpoint and try to inspect a value by entering its name in the *Watch* panel, I get the following error:

[image]

That's clear enough.  I need to add the `projectName` property to `launch.json` ... I assumed that would be the `<name>` field in the `.project` file that VSCode generated from the `pom.xml` file.  But when I add that to `launch.json`, it then tells me that it can't find the project:

[image]

So, I'm guessing that it's looking for something different as the project name, but I don't know what that would be.  If you can help, I would appreciate it.  :o)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code projectName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490671/visual-studio-code-projectname)

Answer (score 0):

Someone else had the same problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696053/8273587

Specifically, I've been using the project name found in `.project` as well. As it turns out, I needed to use the Artifact ID in the relevant `pom.xml`